# Copy data from one server to another in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to copy data from one server to another server in Linux Debian using this command in Putty :

```
 scp -r khader@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/khader/backup/ khader@yy.yyy.yyy.yyy:/home/khader/
```

It is asking for password

```
khader@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

When I type the password, it says

```
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: Enabling verbose mode (-v option) is a good start point to debug such issues.

Comment: Thanks for all who viewed my post. The issue has been solved. I used this command : `scp /local_directory/local_file username@hostname_or_IP_address:~/remote_directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [in comment](https://superuser.com/questions/417488/copy-data-from-one-server-to-another-in-linux#comment477012_417488):

Used this command

```
 scp /local_directory/local_file username@hostname_or_IP_address:~/remote_directory
```